# Angular ng-select tag input - need to create tag onfocusout

Tags: javascript, angular, tags, angular-ngselect

In **ng-select** , user need to hit enter key after typing to create a tag. But in my scenario tags also need to be created when user remove the **focus** from **ng-select** element after typing (When user type and leave without press enter key). Here is the HTML part. Using this inside a angular reactive form.

```
<ng-select placeholder="Tags" [items]="[]" [addTag]="true" [multiple]="true" [selectOnTab]="true" [isOpen]="false" formControlName="tags"> </ng-select>
```

Please let me know your ideas.. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "blur" event [as described in the ng-select repo](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#outputs)

You would just have to add (blur)="someEvent()" to your ng-select.

EDIT:

To listen to a keypress on the enter key you can do this:

Do you mean to listen for an enter keypress event? Absolutely!

You can use the keyup event:

```html
(keyup)="someAction($event)"
```

Then in the component you can do something like this:

```
someAction(event) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // enter key was pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to trigger enter key press on ng-select element?

Comment: Do you mean to listen for an enter keypress event? Absolutely! I've edited my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: Not actually. I mean pragmatically trigger enter key press on  a HTML element.

Comment: You just want to trigger the "create tag" event though right? You can just trigger that event when the user actually presses the enter key (the edit I added) and when the user leaves the element (the blur event). You don't need to programmatically trigger the "enter" keypress. You should try to keep the triggers as close to the actual behavior as you can. Triggering a keypress event on the on blur event could become very difficult to maintain in the future.